# material-ui using json data on single page application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I need to initialize a react component with some json data, but don't know how to do this with material-ui:

This is how I would do in react:

```
var CommentList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var commentNodes = this.props.data.map(function (comment) {
      return (
        <Comment author={comment.author}>
          {comment.text}
        </Comment>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div className="commentList">
        {commentNodes}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

React.render(
  <CommentBox url="comments.json" />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

But I'm now using single page application with [material-ui](http://material-ui.com/) and routes where all the pages are loaded by react but I don't know how to pass the json to each individual page. I would like to use it the following way where I send the comments.json to my home component:

```
<Route name="root" path="/" handler={Main}>
   <Route name="home" url="comments.json" handler={Home} />
   <DefaultRoute handler={Home}/>
</Route>
```

Is it possible to achieve this somehow?

Comment: are you loading the `json` asynchronously (ajax)?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean but the data should be loaded asynchronously which I thought would happen in the background of the Route component and then it will pass over that as props to the Home component? Or do I need to load the data somehow in my Home component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to load the `json` in the `componentWillMount` method using something like [jquery ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/):

```
var CommentList = React.createClass({
  componentWillMount: function () {
    $.get('comments.json').done(function (json) {
      this.setState({comments: json});
    }.bind(this));
  },
  render: function() {
    var commentNodes = this.state.comments.map(function (comment) {
      return (
        <Comment author={comment.author}>
          {comment.text}
        </Comment>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div className="commentList">
        {commentNodes}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

You could obviously do the ajax call in your `Main` component and pass the data through as props but you'll get the idea.